# Align elements in the same row using material

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, material-design

I am using Material Design in my angular application. A lookup is loading all dashboards using the md-card element. The problem is currently one item is loading into one row, whereas i need to load 3 elements into one row.

**HTML:**

```
 <div ng-controller="DashboardCtrl">
      <md-content>          
            <md-card layout="row" class="lookupdashboard" onload="LoadAll()" md-theme="teal" ng-repeat="x in ExistingDashboardDetails" >
               <md-card-content>
                  <h7>{{x.name}}</h7>                                              
               </md-card-content>
            </md-card>
        </md-content>
  </div>
```

Here is the [`Plunker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/wcTa47xMkIMz6FZEZ6sN?p=preview):

Comment: Your plunker only shows one item in the row... can you update the plunker so that 3 items are showing up in the row... then we can help you style it so 3 items get aligned in one row...

Comment: @Lowkase That is my question, aligning 3 items in one row using material, btw i know to style when they are aligned in the same row

Comment: ahhh, got ya.  Thought this was a styling question.

Comment: I get `Unable to connect to any application instances.` when opening your plunkr

Comment: @darryn.ten try in different browser